# How do I inherit class with FlowType?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flowtype

Use React(ReactNative).

Want to inherit Component class, but in that case happen trouble with flow error.

[TryFlow](https://flow.org/try/#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-MIZshGU1eWoIA)

```
/* @flow */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

type commonProps ={
  actions: Object,
};

type someProps = commonProps & {
  someNumber: number,
};

class CustomComponent extends Component<commonProps> {
  static defaultProps: {};
  props: commonProps;
}

class MyComponent extends CustomComponent {
  props: someProps;

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>{this.props.someNumber}</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

What to do???

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should set type annotation for classes. Like this:

```
class CustomComponent<commonProps> extends Component<Props, State> {
   static defaultProps: {};
   props: commonProps;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In that case, `Can not resolve name` is returned.
[TryFlow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBcwAlAUwEMBjQgGjAG8wBhOXOAOzI+IF8wo+NmADk+SjREBudKkIBPHGTBU2WTgAUhOAM5gAvA1Rgw1Qhk46AXGADyAIwBWZGrVS8Zcxcp1syWuF0DFTVNbT0AMkZjMF8sMgA5AFcsezJ8Gw4UtPw3D3QqGAodPWYknUI2VnYuHjAyAA9CbgATUrY8WsIAHgDdegBlQgpmgD5okwqRjCowFrIoCiSYQj7rRnyTHHCbVSx1DjWZXlQgA)

Comment: Because you need set type for a State, if you will have the state. 
Try it `class CustomComponent extends Component<commonProps> {}`